# Aplicar Material Design (android:Theme.Material) para versões do Android menores que API 21?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Estava estudando uma pouco sobre as diretrizes de layout do Android como:

- [Cores](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#);
- [Material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#);
- [E como implementar essas diretrizes](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette);

Então tentei customizar meu *theme*, assim:

```xml
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Mas os atributos, `android:colorPrimary`, `android:colorPrimaryDark` e `android:colorAccent`, só está disponível para versões recentes do Android (API 21+), que atualmente não é meu *target*.

Então tomei outro caminho, customizar os componente manualmente. Então tentei setar a cor do StatusBar, com o método [`setStatusBarColor(int color)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)), só que este também não está disponível para versões anteriores a API 21.

**Perguntas:**

1. Há alguma forma de setar uma cor sólida para o StatusBar, para Android API 21- (Seja XML, ou código)?
2. Há algum AppCompat, que proporcione compatibilidade dos temas ["Material"](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) com versão menores que API 21?
3. Há alguma outra forma de obter esse resultado, para Android API 21-?

**Observações importantes**

- Meu `minTarget` é API 14.

Comment: Você leu essa parte? http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: @LucasSantos, pior que não tinha visto. Hehe. Estou criando um projeto de teste, para tentar implementar isso. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: com certeza vai dar certo. Eu implementei no meu projeto e funcionou. De nada.

Comment: @LucasSantos, em meu projeto de teste até funcionou, mais ainda assim, não alterou a cor do StatusBar como citado [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette), onde a cor do StatusBar é para ser a `colorPrimaryDark`, estou executando em um Android 4.2, e o StatusBar continuo preto, mesmo tento definido com `colorPrimaryDark` no `style` com azul. Será que esse é o comportamento correto? Obs: O ActionBar trocou de cor como esperado.

Comment: Fernando, a cor do **StatusBar** só é alterada com o atributo `colorPrimaryDark` no SDK 21, ou usando **Tinted/Translucent StatusBar** no Android 19. Fora disso não tem como alterar a cor...

Comment: @Wakim, entendi, então na verdade a API de compatibilidade não torna esse comportamento condizente para todas as versões do Android, somente permite utiliza-lo onde o mesmo é permitido, no caso, somente na API 21+, e mesmo assim mantendo o funcionamento sem a _feature_, para versões menores. Certo?

Comment: Exatamente, colorir a **Status Bar** não tem compatibilidade mesmo, mas as demais propriedades como `colorPrimary` e `accentColor` possuem papel, mas a `colorPrimaryDark` apenas na versão 21+.

Comment: @Fernando Tive um problema semelhante que o seu. Precisei alterar a cor das estrelas do RatingBar mas só era disponível para versões iguais/superiores que a Lollipop. Acabei tendo que recorrer a bibliotecas no Github p trocar a cor e ser compatível.

Answer (score 1):

para versões menores que a api 21 é só você criar dois styles 1- para <21 e o 2 para versão >21, segue o exemplo de como implementar em versões menores.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Até entendi sua sugestão, mas no caso não é bem isso que eu quero! O que gostaria quando fiz essa pergunta era manter o mesmo comportamento entre as versões do Android, implementando os temas do **Material Design**, sendo que a biblioteca de compatibilidade indicada por @LucasSantos, resolveu o problema faltando apenas conseguir colorir o **StatusBar**, nas versões inferiores a API 21, o que concluiu-se não ser possível.