# Suporte de temas (Themes) Android em componentes customizados, utilizando AppCompat-v7

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, app-compat-v7

Passei a utilizar o [AppCompat-v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7), para [utilizar o conceito de Material Design em meu projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57519/aplicar-material-design-androidtheme-material-para-vers%C3%B5es-do-android-menores). Só que agora percebi que meus componentes customizados mesmo herdando de componentes nativos, não estão aplicando os temas como os componente nativos, por exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte componente customizado herdando de `android.widget.EditText`:

```
public class EditTextPro extends android.widget.EditText {

    public EditTextPro(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

E em meu layout utilizo o componente `EditTextPro` dessa forma:

```
<com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

E outro com um componente nativo `android.widget.EditText` assim:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Estou utilizando o seguinte tema:

```
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/palette_primary</item> <!-- #3F51B5 = Azul -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/palette_primary_dark</item> <!-- #303F9F = Azul Forte -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/palette_accent</item>  <!-- #FF4081 = Rosa -->
</style>
```

E resultado dos 2 EditText é o seguinte (o primeiro é o `android.widget.EditText` e o segundo o `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro`):

Com o foco no `android.widget.EditText` o `colorAccent` é exibido na linha do `EditText`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já com o foco no `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro` o `colorAccent` não é exibido na linha do `EditText`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E também mesmo sem o foco as cores apresentadas são diferentes, sendo um tom de cinza para o `android.widget.EditText` e Preto para o `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro`

**Perguntas:**

- Por que isso ocorre? Já que não faço nenhuma alteração nos estilos do `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro` em relação ao `android.widget.EditText`, sendo que pela logica (minha logica =D) era para o `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro` herdar todos os estilos do `android.widget.EditText`. Certo?
- Há alguma maneira de resolver isso? Fazer com que o `com.app.materialtest.EditTextPro` tenha os mesmos estilos do `android.widget.EditText`.
- Devo herdar ao invés de `android.widget.EditText` de alguma `EditText` da API de suporte? (Obs: procurei na API de suporte e não encontrei nenhum `EditText`).

> Obs: Estou executando em Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de herdar de `android.widget.EditText` do seu Custom EditText, herde dessa classe e veja se funciona:

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText
```

Link para a classe: [TintEditText.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintEditText.java)

Leia o Javadoc da classe, ele diz:

```
/ **
  * Uma tonalidade ciente {link android.widget.EditText}.
  * <P>
  * Isto será usada automaticamente quando você usa {link android.widget.EditText} em seus
  * Layouts. Você só precisa usar manualmente esta classe ao escrever views personalizadas.
  * /
```

No trecho desta [página (Usando API's de Bibliotecas de Suporte)](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#using-apis) tem um **aviso (Caution)** que é: Ao usar as classes da Biblioteca de Suporte, tenha certeza de importar a classe do pacote apropriado. Por exemplo, quando se aplica a classe ActionBar:
`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` *ao usar a biblioteca de suporte*.
`android.app.ActionBar` *ao desenvolver só para o nível API 11 ou superior.*

Eu interpretei o seguinte, que é, se está usando uma biblioteca de suporte, procure sempre importar ou herdar do pacote apropriado. (Nada mais nada menos do que já está escrito. Rsrsrs :D)

Comment: Incrível que era isso! Muito obrigado. Nossa já tinha tentado tantas coisas que já não tinha mais opções de "gambiarras" para tentar. Perfeito. (Muito melhor que esses gringos, que só dão opções de gambiarras. [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026826/style-inheritance-of-extended-widget), recomendo traduzir e postar sua resposta lá)

Comment: @Fernando De nada, fico feliz em ajudar. Vou traduzir minha resposta e colocar no link que me mandou. Valeu.

Comment: Eu já estou seguindo essa linha de pensamento de sempre utilizar as opções de dentro de `android.support.v7.app`, ao invés do nativo `android.app` (aprendi isso após perder algum tempo tentando entender por que meu `ActionBar` não funcionava como esperado, e era por que estava utilizando o `android.app.ActionBar`), mas no caso do `EditText`, eles sacanearam em trocar o nome `TintEditText`, eu já havia procurado algum `EditText` na API de _support_ e não havia encontrado, hehe.

Comment: Realmente procurar por uma classe que acrescentaram um nome na frente dificulta um pouco mais as coisas. Se o nome fosse o mesmo acredito que a IDE iria te avisar dizendo que tem mais de um lugar para importar e te dando a opção de escolher. Já traduzi minha resposta e coloquei no Stack americano.

Comment: Já recebeu meu +1, lá também, afinal essa opção além de ser mais simples, ela funciona, ao contrário das outras respostas de lá, que funcionam em parte. =)